# How can I make the header and footer on my first page the same as on all subsequent pages?

Tags: fancyhdr

Various versions of this question have been asked before, but they either have special issues (such as a title page) or I simply can't understand the answer.

Here is the start of my latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\textwidth = 7 in
\textheight = 9.5 in
\oddsidemargin = -0.25 in
\evensidemargin = 0.0 in
\topmargin = -0.25 in
\headheight = 0.0 in
\headsep = 0.0 in
\parskip = 0.1 in
\parindent = 0.0 in

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{my name}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
```

The result is that on the first page the header overwrites the text, but the page number is in a good position.  On all remaining pages the header is fine, but the page number is placed too low.  Can anyone offer assistance please?

Comment: Hi and Welcome, a little hint, package `geometry` is better suited to specify the margins. Be sure to load package `fancyhdr` after setting the margins.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile your code, you get this warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.49998pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Hence you have to give proper `headheight` and better way of doing this is through `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{text={7in,9.5in}
,headheight=15pt
}

%\textwidth = 7 in
%\textheight = 9.5 in
%\oddsidemargin = -0.25 in
%\evensidemargin = 0.0 in
%\topmargin = -0.25 in
%\headheight = 0.0 in
%\headsep = 0.0 in
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\rhead{my name}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

For your case, ideal will be to use

```
\geometry{text={7in,9.5in}
,headheight=15pt
,headsep=0.1in
,includehead
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind changing `parskip` and `parindent` to be set using `setlength`?

Comment: @Johannes_B No mind at all ;-). You know the edit button, Please go on. I would comment both the lines as I don't like changing those values at all, personally. :-)